# magento 2.1.5 how to get product disabled status programmatically

Tags: product, magento2, status

I am going to get product's enabled/disabled status programmatically.
Now, we got product instance by this code.

```
 <?php $_product = $_item->getProduct(); ?>
```

Also, using following code part, we can get product stock information.

```
 <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
      $product_is_stock = $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()); ?>
```

**But, is there any solution to get status of product from $_product on Magento 2.1?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After debugging on few hours, I got a good solution about this issue.

```
<?php $_product = $_item->getProduct(); 

 $product_status = $_product->getStatus();
```

In my example, I got deactivated product's status as value using **$_product->getStatus()**.

```
<?php if (($product_is_stock == 0) || ($_product->getStatus() == 2)): ?>
```

To confirm this operation, I got deactivated products using these sql commands.

```
SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
    WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 2
```

Finally, I confirmed deactivated products' status was just 2, not 0.

Enabled products' status was just 1.

Hope my example will help many developers.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in magento core, we can find that **enabled = 1** and **disabled = 2**.

In *Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status.php*

```
 /**
 * Product Status values
 */
const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;

const STATUS_DISABLED = 2;
```

This is from the core code of magento 2.3.0

Use the core Luke!